# refused visitor visa how can we prove he is genuine and will return home

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My fiance applied for a UK visitor visa in December and was refused on paragraph 4.2 (a) and (c). We want to reapply, but how can we prove his circumstances have changed and that he is a genuine visitor and will return to his country. He has a job to go back to as well as a house that he has paid the rent up until next year for, isn't that sufficient to show economic ties to his country and enough to show he will go back?

They said his bank statement showed inconsistent deposits that he didn't prove where they came from, although it stated in his application that a large portion of that was deposited by his mum to go toward his MBA.  Does he need to get her bank statement and a letter from her confirming this, this time as the money is still in his account?

Also he had a professional do his last application and she put me as a family friend which she shouldn't have.  We want to put that I am his fiance on this application.  Is there a way to do that without it causing issues?

[image]

Comment: Listing yourself as fiancée will weaken your fiancé's case for return, which is probably why your  'professional' did things that way. Changing things now will certainly raise questions with the ECO. Misrepresenting things on a visa application (which your fiancé has done here) is taken very seriously and can lead to a lengthy ban. You need to be very careful in how you proceed.

Comment: Make a list of the refusal reasons and plan how to address them. Write a brief (max 3/4 page) cover letter explaining what has changed since the previous application, eg have you become engaged since, and how you maintain your long distance relationship (eg you visit him regularly, frequent calls). Being open about a relationship doesn’t necessarily mean a refusal (I’ve successfully sponsored my partner’s visit twice in the last 18 months).